# LU factorization of a 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

This is the matrix which I'm trying to LU decompose by Gaussian elimination. 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
2&1 &-4 \\ 
2&1 &-2 \\ 
6&3 &-11 
\end{pmatrix}$$
I get to this by performing the row operations:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2&1 &-4 \\ 
2&1 &-2 \\ 
6&3 &-11 
\end{pmatrix} \sim \begin{pmatrix}
2 &1 &-4 \\ 
0&0 &2 \\ 
0&0 &1 
\end{pmatrix} = U $$

$$\therefore L = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &0  &0 \\ 
 1&1  &0 \\ 
 3&0  &1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

This is however obviously incorrect since $$LU\neq A$$
I sslo attempted this problem using partial pivoting but run into the same problem. Can someone guide me where I'm making a mistake and how do I proceed to finding the LU decomposition? p.s. I'm relatively new to Linear Algebra and LU decomposition.

Comment: You miscopied $-4$ as $4$ in $U$. Once you fix this, $LU=A$.

Comment: yes thanks but that is just a typo. still LU is still not equal to A.

Comment: You are multiplying $UL$ instead of $LU$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miscopied $-4$ as $4$ in $U$. Once you fix this, $LU=A$.

Comment: $$LU=\begin{pmatrix}
2 &1 &-4 \\ 
0&0 &2 \\ 
0&0 &1 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0  &0 \\ 
 1&1  &0 \\ 
 3&0  &1 
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
-9 &1  &0 \\ 
 6&0  &0 \\ 
 3&0  &0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: You multiplied $UL$.

Comment: oh dear, that was very silly, thank you for pointing that out :)